# Extracting a value based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

Quick question - I have a dataframe (severity) that looks like,

```
                    industryType  relfreq   relsev
 1              Consumer Products 2.032520 0.419048
 2                 Biotech/Pharma 0.650407 3.771429
 3        Industrial/Construction 1.327913 0.609524
 4  Computer Hardware/Electronics 1.571816 2.019048
 5                Medical Devices 1.463415 3.028571
 6                       Software 0.758808 1.314286
 7     Business/Consumer Services 0.623306 0.723810
 8             Telecommunications 0.650407 4.247619
```

if I wanted to pull the relfreq of Medical Devices (row 5) - how could I subset just that value?

I was thinking about just indexing and doing severity$relfreq[[5]], but I'd be using this line in a bigger function where the user would specify the industry i.e.

```
example <- function(industrytype) {
   weight <- relfreq of industrytype parameter

   thing2 <- thing1*weight
   return(thing2)
 }
```

So if I do subset by an index, is there a way R would know which index corresponds to the industry type specified in the function parameter? Or is it easier/a way to just subset the relfreq column by the industry name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that selecting whole row is better, then choose column which you would like to see.

```
frame <- severity[severity$industryType == 'Medical Devices',]
frame$relfreq
```

Answer (score 1):

You would require to first select the row of interest and then keep the 2 column you requested (industryType and relfreq).
There is a great package that allows you to do this intuitively with tidyverse `library(tidyverse)`

`data_want <- severity %>%
subset(industryType =="Medical Devices") %>%
select(industryType, relfreq)`

Here you read from left to right with the `%>%` serving as passing the result to the next step as if nesting.